# how to run a bash script using ssh and xargs across several hosts without the script being copied to each host?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, xargs

how to run a bash script using ssh and xargs across several hosts without the script being copied to each host ?

This Works,
ssh host1.com bash -s < ~/httpd-conf/weblogrotate.sh

This Doesn't work,
cat webserver.hosts  | xargs -I % ssh % bash -s < ~/httpd-conf/weblogrotate.sh
tcsh: Ambiguous input redirect.

cat webserver.hosts
host1.com
host2.com
host3.com

Answer (score 2):

In bash:

```
while read host; do
   ssh $host bash -s < ~/httpd-conf/weblogrotate.sh &
done < webserver.hosts
```

This also runs them in parallel.

I'm sure you can also do it in tcsh but I'm unfamiliar with the syntax of that shell.

Alternatively you can also use GNU parallel rather than xargs which has remote execution over ssh to remote hosts.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [DSSH](http://bashcurescancer.com/dssh-executing-an-arbitrary-command-in-parallel-on-an-arbitrary-number-of-hosts.html). It's a distributed terminal. Execute command once, it will be executed across all of the hosts.

A hosts file is used

```
$ cat hosts
mojito
-l noland kodiak
mojito
kodiak
-C mojito
-i /home/noland/.ssh/id_rsa kodiak
```

Running a command

```
$ ./dssh.sh "uptime" < hosts
mojito:O:0:19:16:45 up 3 days, 14 min,  5 users,  load average: 0.22, 0.22, 0.20
kodiak:O:0:13:24:00 up 20:00,  1 user,  load average: 0.42, 0.16, 0.05
mojito:O:0:19:16:45 up 3 days, 14 min,  5 users,  load average: 0.22, 0.22, 0.20
kodiak:O:0:13:24:00 up 20:00,  1 user,  load average: 0.42, 0.16, 0.05
mojito:O:0:19:16:45 up 3 days, 14 min,  5 users,  load average: 0.22, 0.22, 0.20
kodiak:O:0:13:24:00 up 20:00,  1 user,  load average: 0.42, 0.16, 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Set alias for ssh to avoid all ssh related errors.

```
alias rssh="ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=2 -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 -o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o LogLevel=ERROR"
```

To execute a single command on multiple hosts in parallel using ssh:

```
# cat hosts_inventory.txt | parallel -j 50 --joblog /tmp/log rssh root@{} 'uptime'
```

To execute a script on multiple hosts in parallel using the ssh:

```
# cat hosts_inventory.txt | parallel -j 50 --joblog /tmp/log rssh root@{} 'bash -s < local_script.sh'
```

To check unreachable hosts:

```
awk ' == 255' /tmp/log.txt
```

Note:

- Include list of remote hosts IP or hostname in this file `hosts_inventory.txt`
- Replace your script with this `local_script.sh`
- Replace with your ssh username instead of `root`